# Random shuffling of String array

Tags: java

I need to randomly shuffle the following String Array:

```
String[] cardsSet1 = {"Name1", "Name2", "Name3"};
```

Is there any way to do that

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4228975/how-to-randomize-arraylist

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You can use the built in (as posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13625997/quickest-way-to-randomize-an-array-of-ints-in-java)):

   `Collections.shuffle(Arrays.asList(cardsSet1));`
2. Or re-invent the wheel:

If you want to copy to a new array (keeping the original intact):

```
public static String[] Randomize(String[] arr) {
    String[] randomizedArray = new String[arr.length];
    System.arraycopy(arr, 0, randomizedArray, 0, arr.length);
    Random rgen = new Random();

    for (int i = 0; i < randomizedArray.length; i++) {
        int randPos = rgen.nextInt(randomizedArray.length);
        String tmp = randomizedArray[i];
        randomizedArray[i] = randomizedArray[randPos];
        randomizedArray[randPos] = tmp;
    }

    return randomizedArray;
}
```

Or if you want to do it in place (very similar to the above):

```
public static void RandomizeInPlace(String[] arr) {
    Random rgen = new Random();

    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        int randPos = rgen.nextInt(arr.length);
        String tmp = arr[i];
        arr[i] = arr[randPos];
        arr[randPos] = tmp;
    }
}
```

... I should have asked up front "what did you try"?